# How does one get the coordinates of a hyper-graph created in Wolfram Cloud?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, wolfram-physics

With the new physics project you can create various hyper-graphs from simple rules. How can I download the coordinates of these graphs (show locations and relationship among all the nodes).

For **example**:

[image]

How would I obtain the coordinates of the graph?

I can create the graphs locally using Mathematica on Desktop, but it does not show coordinates:

[image]

If I remove the underscore in my variable (change g_b to gb) I get:

[image]

Comment: Please give an example.

Comment: What example. It’s any visual created on Wolfram Cloud,

Comment: Please show or link to a single hyper-graph whose coordinates you seek.

Comment: https://www.wolframcloud.com/env/96cc745a-1006-4176-9c76-b6c2d2f38edb

Comment: Can you make the permissions `"Public"`?

Comment: Using an `_` is ***not*** allowed in your variables, so of course `g_b` won't work; Try using something like `gb` instead and report back.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks. Changed it to `gb`. Now I get an error. `GraphEmbedding::graph: A graph object is expected at position 1 in GraphEmbedding[].`

Comment: Letting `gb` be the `WolframModel[]` result, what's the result of `Head[gb]`?

Comment: @J.M. I get the exact same error with `Head[gb]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fsp = ResourceFunction["WolframModel"][{{x, y}, {x, z}} -> 
    {{x, z}, {x, w}, {y, w}, {z, w}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, 10, "FinalStatePlot"]
```

[image]

`fsp` is not a `Graph` object, so `GraphEmbedding` will not work:

```
 Head[fsp]
```

> ```
>  Graphics
> ```

We can get the coordinates using `Cases`:

```
coords = Cases[fsp, Disk[x_, ___] :> x, All];
lines = Cases[fsp, _Line, All];

Graphics[{Red, Point@coords, Blue, lines}]
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful, that works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[Another answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/219959/46895) works, however, it is somewhat fragile as other lines and disks might appear in the `Graphics`, which would break the output.

We don't currently have an exposed function to compute the coordinates explicitly for hypergraphs (Wolfram model states), but it is possible to use an internal SetReplace function.

First, install *SetReplace*, which is the paclet Function Repository functions like [WolframModelPlot](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/WolframModelPlot) use.

```
PacletInstall["SetReplace"];
<< SetReplace`
```

Next, compute the hypergraph, coordinates for which you seek:

```
finalState = 
  WolframModel[{{x, y}, {x, z}} -> {{x, z}, {x, w}, {y, w}, {z, 
      w}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, 10, "FinalState"];
```

Finally, we can use [`hypergraphEmbedding`](https://github.com/maxitg/SetReplace/blob/db6f15c7b4ae1be98be5ced0c188859e2f9eef29/Kernel/WolframModelPlot.m#L317), which is an internal *SetReplace* function to compute the coordinates or both vertices and edges:

```
embedding = 
 SetReplace`PackageScope`hypergraphEmbedding["Ordered", 
   "Polygons", {}][finalState]
```

[image: hypergraphEmbedding output]

`embedding` is a `List` with two elements: vertex and edge embeddings. Each of them is a list of rules, with vertex/hyperedge names on the left, and simplified graphics primitives (`Point`, `Line`, or `Polygons`) used to draw them on the right.

They can be passed directly to `Graphics` to get a simplified visualization without styles:

```
Graphics[Map[Last, embedding, {2}]]
```

[image: reconstructed hypergraph visualization]

***Note:*** using internal functions, as described above, is not a good idea in production code. If you need this functionality for production code, let us know [here](https://github.com/maxitg/SetReplace/issues/333), and consider contributing to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
g = RandomGraph[{20,50}];
```

[image]

```
GraphEmbedding[g]
```

(*

{{2.61478, 1.92035}, {2.18823, 2.27752}, {2.7443, 1.1024}, {0.832645, 
  1.53309}, {2.26009, 0.859775}, {0.939014, 0.988081}, {0.875991, 
  1.97174}, {2.90173, 2.59991}, {3.35849, 1.98695}, {2.75026, 
  0.}, {1.63744, 2.18652}, {0., 1.39657}, {2.32558, 
  1.43712}, {2.90984, 2.11739}, {3.42298, 1.49787}, {3.21852, 
  0.823968}, {3.39545, 2.4406}, {1.46319, 1.61825}, {2.4258, 
  2.88171}, {3.21413, 0.336091}}

*)

Comment: This just produce text like this:  TemplateBox[{"Syntax", "sntxf", "\"\:f7c1\:f7c9\:f7c8RowBox[{\"\\:f3b5\\\"\", RowBox[{\"TagBox\", \"[\", \"RowBox\", \"[\", \"\", \"{\", \"RowBox\", \"[\", \"\", \"{\", \"Interpr....